# Magento 2 : URL issue with index.php

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

i have tried with `site.local/index.php/admin_1l9rnp` but automatically redirect to remove slash after url `(site.localindex.php/admin_1l9rnp)` please suggest how to solve this problem.

this is issue : [image]

i want this : [image]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin panel and navigate to Store -> Configuration -> Web -> Search Engine Optimization -> Use Web Server Rewrites    -> Yes/No

If you want to add index.php in url then disable the Use Web Server Rewrites option.

[image]

Comment: my admin login url not working,

Comment: if admin login is not working then you can directly change the value of web/seo/use_rewrites to 0 from database.